# Load JavaScript before Redirecting (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

This is my code. I already tried, flush(); window_location.. but still it fails. What shall I do? I also tested if the value of $result is being passed and it's fine. The only problem is the JavaScript is not loading. I have other codes with this coding structure but works fine and shows the JavaScript before loading.

```
function accsettings()
{
    $this->load->model('admin_model');
    $result = $this->admin_model->accsettings();

    if ($result==0)
    {
        echo '
            <script type="text/javascript">
                alert("Congratulations! Your profile has been updated.");
            </script>
            ';
        $res2 = $this->admin_model->accset_audit();

    }
    else if ($result==1)
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("Error! Current password is not correct."); </script>';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<script type="text/javascript"> alert("New password does not match with the confirmation."); </script>';
    }
    redirect('/main/accsettings');
}
```

Comment: This will never work. You first print some output and then send the user to another page. When there is an error you shouldn't redirect the user.

Comment: @Jerodev, I had this exact code on the other functionalities of my program and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend this way to show 'JavaScript' alert message, if you want to show validation message then please set variable controller and check on view.

In you code you are using `header`location method to redirect page that is not show up result on browser.

Please use `refresh` method to show buffer result on browser

```
redirect('/main/accsettings', 'refresh');
//similar to 
header( "refresh:0;url=/main/accsettings" );
```

Comment: Using header results in problems in codeigniter like 404 errors and such.

Comment: are you **redirecting** same controller action?

Comment: "Not Found

The requested URL /main/accsettings was not found on this server."

Edit: main/accsettings is a view found in main.php which is a controller.

Comment: there must be another issue... did  you tried `index.php/main/accsettings` ?

Comment: main is not a folder. accsettings is not a file. main is the file and accsettings is a function inside the file. I hope we don't have any misunderstandings on this one.

Comment: I know main is controller. are able to access url `http://yourdomain.com/main/accsettings` from browser address bar?

Comment: then `redirect('/main/accsettings');` should work, you are trying to redirect page on same action `main/accsettings` this is wrong..

Comment: That's my code. Look! :) HOWEVER, the thing is the JavaScript is not showing first before the page.

Answer (score 0):

You should do the redirect also inside the javascript when you want this to be executed.

Here's how you could achieve this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    alert("Error! Current password is not correct.");
    setTimeout(function () {
        window.location.href = "http://www.google.nl"; //will redirect to google.
    }, 2000); //will call the function after 2 secs.
</script>
```

Comment: href will not work. main is not a folder and accsettings is a function inside the main.php file. I'm using the CodeIgniter framework as indicated in the time.

Comment: Are you redirecting to exactly the same controller & function ?